# Appropriate Obstacles for a "Find and Question" scene

Tags: dusk-city-outlaws

In my game ("The Funeral Job" from the Judge's Rulebook) my players want to ask Arianna of Southton questions about the Gorgov family necklace. This seems like a good opportunity for a legwork scene where they have to find her within the church and then ask her questions.

My question is how this fits within the mechanical structure of DCO.

Specifically, is finding her the **obstacle**, or is interrogating her the **obstacle**?

Also, as they question her, does that automatically count as a **drama scene** of interrogation, or can it just be handled using skill rolls (e.g. lie/convince) without attacks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, there are a few ways you could approach this, but I'll give you my quick take on how I'd do it at my table.

So, the *goal of the scene* is not to find her or interrogate her, it's to get the information. So, everything related to getting the information is the core challenge of the scene. As such, I would say the player leading the scene (with the help of the other players) must, over the course of the scene, whittle Ariana's luck down to 0 in order to get what they want out of the scene, since she is a minor villain (statistically treated as a Calculating Noble, per the scenario). Any time a specific non-minion enemy is the direct target of the scene, I tend to consider that prime fodder for a drama scene, even one that is more of a clash of wills and wits than one of violence, especially since the danger they face is her seeing through them and alerting the rest of her family to the crew's intentions. Unless they really botch things, they will probably be able to get what they want, but the important part about this drama scene is that she will have opportunities to attack the heroes as well, chipping away at their luck, and maybe generating a little heat in the process. During legwork, even small hits to your luck or additions to the heat pool can mean big problems down the line, especially is crew members are forced to blow off steam and sit out a later legwork scene.

(You absolutely could handle it as just a single check, if you want the scene to go quickly; I just thing, given the risk involved in dealing with a minor villain who is directly involved in the Job's core conceit, this one works better as a drama scene)

Now, that's the core conflict, but you also asked about the *obstacle* in the scene. Obstacles should be stumbling blocks and impediments outside of the core goal of the scene. Behind the curtain, they are a reason for crew members other than the one leading the scene to get involved, so you don't have a bunch of players sitting idle during other folks' legwork scenes. So, for this one, you'd want the obstacle to be an hurdle to overcome, above and beyond getting the info out of her.

Since they are planning on going to the cathedral she lives in to confront her there, I can think of a bunch of fun possible obstacles:

- A priest who oversees the cathedral decides coincidentally to pay Ariana a lengthy visit the day the crew decides to go to the cathedral, and he must be redirected/subdued to get unfettered access to her
- Since (spoiler alert) Ariana has deeply indebted herself, maybe a Family or Forgotten loan shark has come to collect, and the crew runs the risk that the loan shark will blow the crew's cover if not dealt with first
- Since the city's cathedrals are "neutral ground" for the Right Kind of People and the City Watch alike, an officer of the Watch (one who has had a brush with the heroes in the past) is at the cathedral for a church service of some kind, and the crew has to get the officer away before they can approach Ariana lest they be identified
- When the crew arrives, Ariana is handing out alms to the poor, many of whom are street urchins belonging to Forgotten gangs. One of the urchin gangs has decided to try and rob Ariana, and is likely to botch the attempt and draw the attention of the City Watch; the crew has to either run the urchin gang off, or help them with their petty thievery so they don't get caught.

Stuff like that. Something to spice up the scene before the questioning truly begins.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm still a little unclear on the line between "obstacle" and "core conflict", and this really helps me work it out. I got from the rules that once you were past the obstacles, you always got what you needed, rather that this could then lead you into a proper conflict.

I've also worked out I'm too hesitant to go into a drama scene at the moment.

I think I made the right call for my group of not turning it into a full fledged interrogation (especially as I've decided Arianna's knowledge of the necklace is limited), but it's good to get more clarity on how this works.